# How to add 64-bit numbers in MIPS Assembly?

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

I am wondering how I would deal with adding two 64-bit numbers. I currently have this code, made in MARS Simulator:

```
#A*B
    multu $s0, $s1
    mfhi $t4
    mflo $t5
#C*D
    multu $s2, $s3
    mfhi $t6
    mflo $t7
```

The values **$s0-3** have already been set previously in the code via user input and are *unsigned*(but their max values are 2147483647 due to how syscall works).
Essentially, I'm trying to do ($s0$s1 + $s2$s3) without causing overflow by returning a 64-bit number in the form of two 32-bit values representing the most and least significant bits.

Comment: Which part is causing you problem? Use two 32 bit additions, and handle the carry.

Comment: Compiler output using `uint64_t` should make a good example of how to manually handle carry-out.  https://godbolt.org/  I assume you're using 32-bit MIPS, so you can't just use `daddu`.

Comment: How would I go about carrying the bit, avoiding an overflow error? I have heard that SLTU is good since when overflowing, the result is a number that is less than the two numbers added.

Comment: Yes, use `sltu`. That will directly produce a carry bit that you can add to the top half.